# OpenJDK - Oracle is better?

Tags: java, openjdk

From http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Type/Copy/Paste: java -version . If you're having

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10pre) (7b15~pre1-0lucid1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

... you have the wrong vendor version of Java installed for this exercise.

This is what I have. I wonder, why is this a wrong vendor? What is this vendor? Why should I use Oracle Java instead?

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why you rolled back my edit? I didn't change anything about the content.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, why did you edit it at all?

Comment: See the edit comment.

Comment: Since I answered your question, would you give me the courtesy to answer mine: why did you roll my edit back?

Comment: Why always nice questions get closed ??

Comment: As of 2021 this has drastically changed.  The OpenJDK coming with Ubuntu is good enough for almost all purposes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are currently two Java versions (vendors, if you will) available:

- Oracle's (previously Sun) JDK, the closed source Java, with commercial support from Oracle 'n stuffs.
- OpenJDK, the open source Java. Oracle released part of their source and renamed it.

In the days of Java 6, there used to be a big difference between the two of them, OpenJDK running slower and supporting less. However, nowadays, except for the java-web-plugin (which was rewritten by the community and named icedtea-web), they are exactly the same. Neither of the two versions is "wrong".

There are still people claiming OpenJDK is worse than Oracle's JDK, but it's become a myth.

I recommend keeping OpenJDK for Java 7, because open source FTW, and because it's supported in the official repositories of Ubuntu (Oracle does not let others redistribute their JDK).

Comment: for example, `$ javac -version
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:` - should it be so with OpenJDK?

Comment: OpenJDK is also the [reference implementation](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the) of Java SE 7, so I think that's a testament to its stability (if I'm understanding correctly what it means to be a reference implementation).

Comment: @Alex Java (OpenJDK and Oracle) is split in two packages: The Java Runtime Environment (JRE), and the Java Development Kit (JDK). If you just want to run some java programs, the JRE is all you need. If you want to compile some java programs (javac, which stands for java compiler), you'll need the JDK. Install the JDK with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Comment: I've stopped using OpenJDK when at version 6, because at that time, it was clearly slower than Oracle JDK 1.6. Thus, I have no hands on proof that Open JDK 1.7 is still as slow as compared to Oracle JDK 1.7. I've found however some benchamrks made by other ppl, claiming that there still is a performance difference (in favour of Oracle JDK): http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/linux-a-unix/37-openjdk-vs-oraclejvm-a-look-at-java-performance-under-redhat-6-3-with-specjvm2008.html?start=3 I'd like to know if there's also proof stating the contrary (as I *do* prefer OpenJDK's... openness :) )

Comment: Back when jdk6, the winner was hands-down oracle. Now, I tried running minecraft and intellij with both, and there is no noticeable difference. The only "proof" you can have is trying it yourself, the fact that openjdk is the reference implementation, and this blog post: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/robogeek/archive/2009/01/05/it-will-be-openjdk7-where-openjdkjdk

Comment: Also, the benchmarks show little difference between the two. It is possible that if the guy did the tests again, openjdk would win by some miliseconds. Performance differs from system to system, and benchmarks aren't as accurate as you might expect. Therefor, I suggest relying more on your experience than benchmarks.

Comment: @ShivanDragon, isn't the performance difference negligible? I think it is, you won't the difference at all. –

Comment: On Ubuntu the openJDK 6, 7 and 8 have a font bug on SWING that let the font ugly. They say that it is fixed on Oracle JDK I will test it later