# Why isn't Oracle Java included in the standard Ubuntu repo?

Tags: java, ppa, oracle, legal

Unlike many popular programming languages, the popular Oracle Java package [is only available using a PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html), not by the official repo.

Why isn't Oracle Java included in the standard Ubuntu repo?

Comment: Some additional and maybe interesting links about OpenJDK vs OracleJDK: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22358071/4464570 and http://askubuntu.com/q/437752/367990.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ubuntu has OpenJDK in its repository. It's the fully open-sourced version of the [Oracle JDK, which contains some closed-source parts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171140).

It is a myth that OpenJDK is lower and less stable, but this was the past.
Today (since version 7), they're pretty equal. OpenJDK is even the reference implementation for [Java 7](https://jdk7.java.net/java-se-7-ri/) and [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/java-se-8-ri/). It's a race between those two implementations, as some new features appear first in OpenJDK and then later get included to OracleJDK, while some features get included the other way round.

The major differences are that OpenJDK has no Webstart included (but the open-source IcedTea does this job) and some other closed-source tools of Oracle missing, but nothing important.

So to sum up: [As Ubuntu supports everything that is open-source](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy), it supports OpenJDK, especially as it has no real disadvantages any more.

Comment: *OpenJDK is even the reference implementation for Java 7.* - by whom?

Comment: https://jdk7.java.net/java-se-7-ri/ or https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the should both prove that statement, as does every reliable source on the web.

Comment: no offense meant here. You were making a strong argument in favor of openJDK, and it would make sense to support that argument with a canonical reference.

Comment: No problem, I did not feel offended. I just wasn't 100% sure I correctly understood you. :)

Comment: Thanks, it's a real relief. Mind if I edit your answer to inline the link? Do you have any link to the fact that Oracle JDK is close-source?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/171129 but OracleJDK is not fully closed-source, I think, because the code of OracleJDK and OpenJDK are nearly equal. It's just small closed-source parts (e.g. some code for graphics) and additional tools. And if you feel you can improve any post somehow, just do the edit. If I don't like it, I can roll it back anyway. No need to ask.

Comment: The problem is that many web applications require Oracle Java. OpenJDK just does not work.

Comment: My way through the internet did not pass any site that would have forced me to install Oracle Java yet... You just need IcedTea for Java Applets in browsers if you use OpenJDK, while this is already included in Oracle Java.

Comment: The original question was "Why isn't Oracle Java included in the standard Ubuntu repo" and not "What can I use as a substitute in Ubuntu instead of OracleJDK".  And I think the answer should be explaining some legal reasons.

Comment: @karatedog More elaboration could be useful, but "some of the source is closed" is a good start.

Comment: Just to second Pilot6's point, since I personally experienced severe issues when using Java apps from my company with OpenJDK a few years ago. I don't remember the specifics, but I remember I was able to get them to work correctly by switching to OracleJDK instead. Of course, this is anecdotal and could be the result of bugs that might have been fixed in the meantime, so take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: The only bug I've experienced so far with OpenJDK is in OpenJFX (the Java FX implementation). If using OpenJFX, then fonts from files can't be loaded.

Comment: @Smig It would have been interesting which Java version this was. As stated in the answer, until version 6 OpenJDK was indeed not as good as Oracle's implementation in many points, but with version 7 they became pretty equal in performance and stability.

Comment: @ByteCommander I had a fresh Ubuntu at hand, so out of curiosity I decided to install OpenJDK and try those same java apps out, and I couldn't find any problems with them anymore. Just wanted to leave this here for the record, so that problems I might have faced with previous versions don't steer people away from OpenJDK as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's caused by licence:

- [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is licensed under the GNU General Public License (GNU
  GPL)
- [Oracle JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) is licensed under 'Sun License'

To be honest, I would prefer to have Oracle Java in Ubuntu/Ubuntu-based since (unfortunately) some applications still demand it.