# Getting java plugin into firefox

Tags: java, openjdk, icedtea

I want the java plugin to work in Firefox and so I want to be clear on something.
It appears that the default JRE (OpenJDK) that one gets from doing

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

will not work, and so it is useless.  One needs either `icedtea-8-plugin:i386` or `oracle-java8-installer`.  Is this right?

Previous answers to questions about this just say install icedtea, but do not explain why?  I am asking specifically if this is because openjdk cannot be made to work in Firefox.  And I am wondering why in the world that would be?  Strikes me as absolutely crazy.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts for a typical open- source installation.  For `oracle-java8-installer` you need to add a PPA:  https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Comment: "Beginning in Firefox version 52, support for NPAPI plugins (java applets) in Firefox has ended" Firefox provides some assistance with installing Oracle's version: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Manage-preferences-and-add-ons/Use-the-Java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content-on-websites/ta-p/3244

Answer (score 6):

Oracle Java contains some additional closed-source features like the webstart browser plugin and a few more which are not included in the completely open-source OpenJDK implementation.

However, the IcedTea project provided an additional open-source package that adds the webstart functionality to OpenJDK.

So to run Java applets in any browser (Firefox has nothing to do with that), you need to

- either install the proprietary Oracle Java implementation via a PPA that includes the browser plugin,
- or install the additional `icedtea-8-plugin` package that adds an open-source browser plugin for the open-source OpenJDK Java implementation, with both packages being provided by the official Ubuntu repositories.

Possibly interesting further read: [Why isn't Oracle Java included in the standard Ubuntu repo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/645429/367990)